# 2 networks one wifi router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

I have 2 different networks, one that CAN NOT be connected to the internet (has multiple different switches and devices) and another one where I get my internet access. Is there a wifi router that I can use and set up to let me communicate with both networks without communicating with eachother. Right now I am using a hard line from my computer to the special network and a wifi connection to the internet. If I use 2 different routers then I can only use one or the other not bolth. I also would like to be able to connect up to 3 different networks but they can NOT talk to eachother but that is less of a priority.

Answer (score 1):

Connecting networks is pretty much the job of a router. Not the "wifi router" variety, though, *just* a router. Instead of a bundle of ports going to the same "LAN", *each* port on a router goes to its own network – e.g. port 1 goes to the LAN switch, port 2 goes to the 'isolated' switch, port 3 goes to Internet.

The way this is supposed to work is that the Wi-Fi still connects you to *one* network at a time (your "main" LAN), but the router allows packets to go from one subnet to another (depending on the configured routes). Preventing some networks from accessing the Internet is done using *firewall* configuration on the router – for example, if you want to allow "LAN→Internet" and "LAN→isolated" but not "isolated→Internet", you can literally translate that to (approximately 3 or 4) firewall rules.

The one critical thing however is that all of the networks must be *numbered* differently. For example, if your LAN *and* the isolated network are both using the same 192.168.1.x/24, it's not going to work.

[image]

Probably all "prosumer" or "enterprise" routers can be used this way – though many of them are wired-Ethernet only, with Wi-Fi provided by separate "access point" device(s) – and *some* "home wifi" routers can, though I couldn't name one. (Sometimes home wifi routers allow splitting off some of the LAN ports for additional networks using "VLANs".)

Comment: Hmm, would "interface" be a better word to put what "port" refers to in the above? I think the OP might find it even confusing when you mention home router / VLAN at the end, since they are quite different from the "just router" you were talking about. When I first read your answer I thought you were talking about using multiple IP subnets within a broadcast domain (the only LAN) and apply source IP-based filtering on LAN-WAN forwarding (which is kind of useless unless there's an additional layer of port - source IP filtering set up in the "builtin" switch).